# nnet model fails when specifying x and y arguments instead of a formula

Tags: r

I'm building a single=hidden-layer neural network using the `nnet` package. I've prepared all my data (i.e. center, scaled, converted factors to numerical) and am now in a position to actually fit the model.

According to the `nnet` documentation, the functions arguments can be entered in 1 of 2 ways:

1. Using a formula of the form class ~ x1 + x2
2. Using a `data.frame` of x values for examples and a `data.frame` of target values.

After some research, I've chosen to do the latter as apparently its more memory efficient.

**Model using formula approach**

```
model2 <- nnet(Cohort ~ . -Cohort,
           data = train.min, 
           size = 30,
           decay = 0.1,
           maxit = 200, 
           MaxNWts = 1500)
```

**Model using x,y approach**

```
model <- nnet(x = train.min[, 1:32], 
          y = y = data.frame(train.min[, 33]), 
          size = 30, 
          decay = 0.1, 
          maxit = 200, 
          MaxNWts = 1500)
```

My problem is, for some reason if I build a model using the formula approach, everything works fine. BUT, when I try using the x, y approach, I get the following error after executing the code:

> Error in nnet.default(x = train.min[, 1:32], y = target, size = 30, decay = 0.1,  : 
>     NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 2)

To troubleshoot, I first checked to make sure my x,y input arguments where of the right class:

```
class(train.min[, 1:32]) # "data.frame"
class(data.frame(train.min[, 33])) # "data.frame" w/ Cohort element, factor (2 levels)
```

I've also checked for any data types which may be casting as chr instead of factors (which is all fine). I've also checked for NA's but my data is clean.

What could be the cause for the formula approach to work yet the x,y approach does not? I feel like I don't know what to test for next.

Comment: Looking at the code, the second and third lines of `nnet.default` are `x <- as.matrix(x); y <- as.matrix(y)`, so I would suggest passing `x` and `y` as matrixes rather than data frames, and making sure that the matrix `x` makes sense. So if you have any categorical variables, use `model.matrix()` on `x` first to convert them to dummies.

Comment: And I think you should convert `y` to binary 0/1, if you look at `nnet.formula` this is done in the case `y` is a factor. This is somewhat suggested by the Details of `?nnet`: "*If the response in formula is a factor, an appropriate classification network is constructed; this has one output and entropy fit if the number of levels is two... If the response is not a factor, it is passed on unchanged to nnet.default.*" Reading between the lines, only if `y` is *not* a factor can it be passed unchanged to `nnet.default`.

Comment: Overall, I think you need to do most of the processing that `nnet.formula` does before calling `nnet.default`, which may make you reconsider whether or not it's worth not using the formula interface.

Comment: I'll give that a shot now. But, if they specify that a `data.frame` can be used as inputs I can't see the matrix making a difference. Is there much overhead using the `nnet.formula` approach? Thanks for your response.

Comment: Look at the code of `nnet::nnet.formula` - it's not that long, and you can see exactly what it does (just some processing before calling `nnet.default`). If you have categorical variables, model matrix with dummies vs data.frame with factors is a very big difference. If you have `factors` in `x` your whole data frame is converted to a *character* matrix rather than a *numeric*, which is a disaster. The `factor` y is also converted to a `character` matrix with `as.matrix()`, so it really is a big difference.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I should have probably looked through the source before making the post, but thank you anyway. If you want to write up these ideas into an answer I'd happily accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nnet.default` immediately coerces data frames provided with `as.matrix`. This will cause major problems if you have any non-numerics in your `y` or `x`. If you have any factor columns in `x`, your whole data frame will be coerced to a character matrix.

The `?nnet` help page is not clear on this, but if you have a binary response it should be coded as 0/1, not a factor. Factors in `x` should be converted to numeric dummy variables. All this is taken care of in `nnet.formula`, which just processes the inputs a little bit before calling `nnet.default`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'll do some more research. Quick question, when converting a 2 level factor to a numerical 0/1, are we talking a single numerical column of either 0 or 1... or two columns corresponding to 0, 1 or 1, 0

Comment: For a typical linear model, a factor with `k` levels needs `k - 1` dummy columns - one level, the "reference level", is implied by all the others being 0. "One-hot" encoding usually means using `k` columns. Without an intercept term, as in the neural net, one-hot encoding is probably preferable (but I don't have much neural net experience). You can generate it with `model.matrix()` by putting `+ 0` in the formula, which will remove the intercept column and use `k` columns for each factor with `k` levels.